# Generate a random number in that falls into a multiple range

Tags: python, random

How would I go about generating a random integer in python that ***is*** random but falls into a multiplication table *(times table)* range per se and is determined by a value I specify?

**Example.** Say i want to generate a random number between 10 and 100 but it should be a multiple of 7. Possible return values could be `14, 28, 49, 77` etc.

A mockup of the function could look like this:

```
def gen_random(f, min, max):
    #generate random number between min and max that is a multiple of fac
```

Is Python's `random` module capable of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just generate a multiplier of `fac` that gives you a number between your bounds?

```
import math
import random

def rand_multiple(fac, a, b):
    """Returns a random multiple of fac between a and b."""
    min_multi = math.ceil(float(a) / fac)
    max_multi = math.floor(float(b) / fac)
    return fac * random.randint(min_multi, max_multi)
```

Comment: This can return a value outside the given range. (i.e. `7, 10, 100 -> 7`)

Comment: In Python 2.x's division, if you put in 7 and 10 as integers, yes. That can be fixed by using 7.0 and 10.0 or just adding `float()` casts. In Python 3 it works fine. I'll edit in float casts for the people using Python 2.x though.

Comment: perfect.. :) there was this other guy but he deleted his answer.. heh

Comment: Throughout posterity when someone reads this answer s/he's going to think, *I wonder what the other answer was.*

Answer (score 3):

Function randrange has a step parameter, so if you can do something like this:

```
>>> min = 7
>>> max = 14 + 1
>>> randrange(min, max, 7)
14
>>> randrange(min, max, 7)
7
```

but:

```
>>> min = 6
>>> randrange(min, max, 7)
13
```

so you need to do something like this:

```
min += 7 - min % 7
max = max - max % 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually check for the factor parameter; the random function does not handle that. You could generate a number between min/f and max/f then multiply by f as your final result.